# Preciso encontrar regex para analisar uma variável

Tags: javascript, regex, expressões-lambda

Preciso analisar um código C usando regex e estou com dificuldades na hora de saber se uma variável está recebendo um valor float ou inteiro.

Ex:

```
valor_01 = ( 5 * 3 ) / 2.5 + ( 4 % 3 ) ^ 4 ;
```

1. `valor_01` pode ser qualquer nome de variável, algo como um `\w+`
2. preciso capturar se depois do `=` e antes do `;` tem algum valor decimal (`2.5` nesse exemplo)
3. até agora cheguei a seguinte expressão:

```
(\w+\s?\=\s?).+
```

Problema: com essa expressão eu pego o nome da variável, o igual e tudo que tiver na linha e não consigo apenas saber se tem um `(\d+.\d+)` e um `;` no final da linha.

É como se eu precisasse capturar

> valor_01 = 2.5 ;

Comment: Embora seja possível, não sei se regex é a melhor solução, pois além de verificar o número, ela teria que verificar o contexto. Por exemplo, se o número estiver dentro de uma string: `valor = "abc 2.5";`, não deveria aceitar, já que a variável está recebendo uma string e não um float. E se tiver alguma variável `float` na expressão? ex: `valor = 1 / x;`, sendo que `x` é uma variável float que foi criada anteriormente. E você também pode fazer `valor = .5;` ou ainda `valor = 1e-2;` (notação científica), que também são `floats`. Enfim, há variações demais e talvez não valha a pena usar regex

Comment: Quem sabe um analisador léxico seja mais adequado (nunca usei isso, mas começaria procurando por algo do tipo). Outra dica: se for mesmo usar regex, `\w+` aceita coisas como `123ab`, que [não é um nome válido para variáveis](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-variables-constants#variable-rule), então mude para `[a-zA-Z_]\w+` (ou ainda, `[a-zA-Z_]\w{0,n}` para limitar a quantidade de caracteres em `n + 1` (embora isso considere `_` um nome válido, e acho que seja, apesar de estranho).

Comment: Mais um caso complicado: `valor = func(2.5)` -  a função `func` pode até receber um `float`, mas e se ela retorna um `int` (ou qualquer outra coisa)? Além da regex já ser complicada por si só (para tratar os casos que já comentei acima), ela ainda teria que analisar esse tipo de coisa, e no fundo você estaria escrevendo um mini-compilador de C em JavaScript (o que é já é complicado por si só, se for se basear em regex pra isso então...)

Comment: E se a linha estiver dentro de um comentário? Nesse caso, deveria ignorar, pois a variável não está recebendo nenhum valor (afinal, está comentado). Só lembrando que não basta verificar se tem `//` na linha, pois C também tem [comentários multi-linha](http://syque.com/cstyle/ch4.6.htm). Enfim, são casos demais para analisar e a regex ficaria absurdamente complexa...

Answer (score 0):

Não vejo a necessidade de validar o nome da variável. Nomes de variáveis não podem conter pontos, se existir um ponto em qualquer trecho da string, significa que há um float.

De qualquer forma, se você quer validar toda a expressão:

`\w+` letras ou números ou underscores

`\s*` seguidos ou não de espaços

`=` seguidos de um igual

`[\d\+\-\*\/\s]*` seguidos ou não de números, expressões algébricas e espaços

`\.\d` seguidos de um ponto seguido de um número

`[\d\+\-\*\/\s]*` seguido ou não de números, expressões algébricas e espaços

`;` seguidos de um ponto e virgula

Ou seja `\w+\s*=[\d\+\-\*\/\s]*\.\d[\d\+\-\*\/\s]*;`

Comment: O problema é que isso valida coisas totalmente inválidas, como `123 = +/- +  .1-**- +;` - além de não aceitar outros casos que menciono [nos comentários acima](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/344239/#comment693101_344239). Apesar desta linha não compilar, ela poderia estar dentro dos comentários, por exemplo (e de qq forma, não foi mencionado se o código sendo analisado compila ou não, então todo cuidado é pouco). Veja [aqui uns exemplos](https://regex101.com/r/jI8vU9/3) desta regex funcionando.